# Testing if functional dependence is the same in two datasets

Tags: regression, model, model-comparison, paired-data

I have the following problem. I have two datasets, the first one composed by pairs (x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>) and the second one by (x'<sub>i</sub>, y'<sub>i</sub>). For instance, these vectors might look like this:

x = [.25 .4 .7 .85 .9 .92]

y = [2.4 1.8 1.35 1.3 1.25 1.1]

x' = [.3 .42 .44 .6 .65 .7 .85 .88]

y' = [2.2 1.9 1.7 1.6 1.65 1.6 1.4 1.2]

Let's also assume for simplicity that the (measurement) errors on **x** and **x'** are negligible compared to those of **y** and **y'**. My question is: is there a way to test whether these measurements are measuring "the same thing"? The thing I am referring to is an unknown functional dependence **y** = f(**x**) which should be the same in both cases.

To simplify things, let's first assume that **x**=**x'** (with both same number of entries and same values). In this case I would first fit a reasonable function (a second order polynomial works quite well for my purposes) to each of the two sets, compute the standard deviation of the residues, and then do some other tests to see whether **y**-**y'** is compatible with a Gaussian variable with zero mean and variance given by the sum of the variances of the residues (that is related to the Z-test, I guess - pardon my sloppiness, I am just a poor biologist). Correct?

However, if **x** does not coincide with **x'** (as in the example above), what should I do? It seems to me that in this case one has to first fit two functions y = f(x) and y'=f'(x'), and then somehow compare *the functions themselves* (considering their confidence intervals, or something like that).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Pretty good analysis for a "poor biologist"!  I would be inclined to conduct a similar evaluation in the simplified case--but I wouldn't insist on Gaussian deviations, since that's not an assumption you made in your description of the data.  It should suffice to check that on the whole the differences $y_i-y_i^\prime$ can be considered the results of accidental independent fluctuations centered at $0$, regardless of their distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, this approach would make sense to me, except that for the case I am interested in I do have **x** /= **x'** ... (but errors should be roughly gaussian)

A friend of mine pointed me towards the Akaike information criterion and its variants (e.g. corrected for sample size). It seems promising to me, but I still have to dig into it. Any comment on that?